# Handling ViewExpiredException depending on the current view

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, viewexpiredexception

I am using JSF 2.0 and Primefaces in my project.

I have two xhtml pages namely Cars.xhtml and Bikes.xhtml.

I am using ViewScoped backing beans.

Currently If get view expired exception from any of the two pages,im handling it in the web.xml.
through the error-page tag and directing to welcome.xhtml.

Now If i get a viewexpired exception from Bikes.xhtml
I need to direct to another page which is  BikesHome.xhtml instead of welcome.xhtml.

If the exception is from Cars.xhtml, welcome.xhtml should be shown.

Please help me how to do.

Answer (score 9):

I not 100% sure about this (because I haven't tried it myself) but here is my suggestion for -
Check this out [Dealing Gracefully with ViewExpiredException in JSF2](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2009/09/03/dealing-gracefully-viewexpiredexception-jsf2).

```java
if (t instanceof ViewExpiredException) {
    ViewExpiredException vee = (ViewExpiredException) t;
```

At this point you can get the `view id` as follows -

```
vee.getViewId();
```

And then based on the `view id` do the desired navigation.

```
NavigationHandler nh = facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
//check condition, set view       
nv.handleNavigation(facesContext, null, "/view-id?faces-redirect=true");
facesContext.renderResponse();
```

Or, I think you could also do -

```
FacesContext.getExternalContext().redirect(url);
FacesContext.responseComplete();
```

to redirect.

Comment: Quick question about the filter in the link you shared, when a timeout is reached the handle() method will be called automatically, will this force a page redirect or will the user need to click something?