# web.xml configuration to redirect to login page after session timeout in jsf

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

Is there any configuration in web.xml which redirects the application to login page after sesion expired in **JSF**.I google it but didn't find any good and simple answer.
I found this but it didn't work.

```
 <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/faces/index.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

If there is no configuration for this then how can i do this in JSF?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible answer: [Handling ViewExpiredException depending on the current view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573135/handling-viewexpiredexception-depending-on-the-current-view).

What I'm using is a PrimeFaces - Extensions specific solution called [AjaxErrorHandler](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/views/ajaxErrorHandler.jsf). Take a look at their showcase for implementation tips.

As far as I know the above configuration will not work for AJAX requests.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible answer: [How to redirect to index page if session time out happend in jsf application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543094/how-to-redirect-to-index-page-if-session-time-out-happend-in-jsf-application)

Yet another possible answer: Use a `JSF PhaseListener`.

---

Additionaly, I suggest using a `Filter` to check if your session is already alive and, if not, redirect to your custom error page (i don't remember where I learnt this method, probably through BalusC):

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
    private FilterConfig config;

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.config = filterConfig;
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("some_attribute_you_store_in_Session") == null){
            ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("yourCustomJSF.jsf");
        }else{
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        this.config = null;
    }

    // You also have to implement init() and destroy() methods.
}
```

Then, you have to declare this filter (and the url patterns that will trigger the filter) in your web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>yourPackage.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>private.jsf</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I store my own bean in my JSF session so I can keep my user information. When the filter receives a `null` return while accessing the class, I know the session has been invalidated (maybe because it has expred, or just the user has logged out) and i redirect the request to my error page.

Comment: If just checking an HttpSession, use this syntax: HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); if (session == null) ... Otherwise it will CREATE a new session. No need for the random session variable.

Answer (score 0):

> *I found this but it didn't work.*

It should work. Most likely you were exclusively using ajax requests. This way the standard `web.xml` error page mechanism won't be used at all. You should instead be using the JSF `ExceptionHandler` facility.

The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has a [`FullAjaxExceptionHandler`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) which is designed for exactly this purpose. It reuses standard `web.xml` error page mechanisms for exceptions/errors during ajax requests. You can find a showcase demo [here](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler). It also handles the `ViewExpiredException`.

#### See also:

- [Why use a JSF ExceptionHandlerFactory instead of <error-page> redirection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534187/why-use-a-jsf-exceptionhandlerfactory-instead-of-error-page-redirection)